# HotKey functionality in HTML page using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 application. I have to implement the save functionality on the ***Ctrl + S*** key.  How can I make this functional using JavaScript/JQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#YourElement').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey)
        {
            // your code to save
        }
    });
});
```

The above jQuery code is using the `keypress` event and checking to see if `s` was typed.  It is also doing a check to see if the Ctrl Key (`event.ctrlKey`) was pressed when the event was fired.

Comment: Thanks..How can i implement this in my project?#WhateverElementToCaptureFor stands for?

Comment: @SinoyDevassy just make your jQuery selector whatever element you want to fire this event for.  In other words, if it's an `input` control, then use that input control's class/id in the selector.  Make sense?

Comment: You may wish to use `$(document).keypress(...)` rather than a specific element, so that users don't have to focus a specific element to use the shortcut.

Comment: Its not getting fired..Its fire browser save option

Comment: event.PreventDetault() missing?